# How to fill down variable series with last variable until end of for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm creating an amortization table and have 30 periods, index is 1-30.  Problem is particular loans haven't come to the end of the 30 periods yet so I have a variable that can change each period.  I have a value for 17 rows, then nothing.  How do I get my variable to fill down to the 30th row with the 17th (last) value in the for loop?

```
beginning_bal = loan_amt
principal = round(nf.ppmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods, per=num_periods, fv=0), 2)
interest = nf.ipmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods, per=num_periods, fv=0)
ending_bal = nf.pv(fv=0, pmt=pmt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=0)
records=[]
end_bal = loan_amt
cum_int = 0.0
cof = 0.0
rt_npv = 0
for i in range(1, len(rng)+1):
    bgn_bal = end_bal
    principal = nf.ppmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods,  per=i, fv=0)
    interest = float(nf.ipmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods, per=i, fv=0))
    end_bal = nf.pv(fv=0, pmt=pmt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=len(rng)-i)
    monthly_co = loan_amt*co_rate
    npv_rate = 1.2**(i / num_payments_per_yr)
    npvper = -pmt / (npv_rate + co_rate + (.014*(12/num_payments_per_yr))) #20% discount, charge off rate, early payoff rate
    rt_npv += npvper
    cof += bgn_bal * .0083 #COF basis
    llr_rate.replace({'llr_rate': {0: np.nan}}).ffill()
    prin_llr = bgn_bal * llr_rate
    int_llr = -interest * llr_rate
    cum_int += interest
    net_revenue = (-cum_int - cof - monthly_co - prin_llr - int_llr)
    records.append((bgn_bal, -pmt, -principal, -interest, -cum_int, end_bal, monthly_co, npvper, rt_npv, npv_rate, cof, prin_llr, int_llr, net_revenue))
```

Comment: Use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas - Fill in df NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898370/python-pandas-fill-in-df-nan-values)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `ffill()`

Explanation: Missing values are replaced with the most recent available value in the same column. So, the value of the preceding row in the same column is used to fill in the blanks.

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Given this example df:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   5   10
1   2   nan 11
2   nan nan 12
3   4   8   nan
4   nan 9   14
```

Result:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   5   10
1   2   8   11
2   2   8   12
3   4   8   12
4   2   9   14
```